# How can I get the "name" attribute in node.js

Tags: node.js

```
<input type='file' name='upload1'/>
```

When this form is submitted,how can I get the "name" attribute (upload1) on node.js.
I use restify,and upload image.

Comment: With *just* Node, it's a bit of a pain, you have to read and decode the [`IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) (which is a readable stream) on the [`request` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request). You might look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/), which is built on Node and provides a more high-level interface. There's also [Getty](http://geddyjs.org/).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Nah, it is easy enough. Especially when using jQueryForm plugin [http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/] and JSON as data type.

Comment: @CodeClown can you upload files using JSON as data type? I thought uploads pretty much required `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @robertklep: you are right. I did not get the input type `file`. I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

The right way in node.js is would be to use a web app framework like express. It gives you more options as well as flexibility. In express you can do :

```
var express = require('express');                     //Initialize express
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.bodyParser());                        //to parse the forms
app.post('/pagesubmit', function(request, response){  //to handle POST to the page
  console.log(request.body.username);                 //tp access input text 'username'
  console.log(request.files.name);                    //to access input file 'name'
});
```

Comment: The `request` object has a [`files`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) property for accessing uploaded files.

Comment: @amesee Thanks I was thinking name to be input type text

Comment: But request.files.name is undefined

Comment: name should be what is on the `name` filed. Like in your question it is upload1, so use request.files.upload1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I don't konw the name filed. How can I get the vaule(upload1) of the name field. Does Node have a method that can get the "name" attribute of input

Comment: You can view all the files under request.file. But in a form there are many fields. Each input has to be identified by their name itself. So getting the name is not a good choice.